Turn off WICKET AJAX DEBUG
I'm running an older version of Wicket with a Jetty web server.  I'm migrating the application to a new server, and simply copied the entire Jetty folder to the new server.  I configured Jetty, Java, etc. and the application comes up and works fine.  Running Jetty as a service.
However, the new server shows the WICKET AJAX DEBUG message in the lower right, which doesn't show on the original server when running the application.  It does show in my development environment.  I'm using the exact same .jar between the 2 servers.
I can't find how to switch the new server to deployment mode.  Since the Jetty directories are the same, maybe it's someplace on the Java side?
Thanks for your help.
Looked for -Dwicket.configuration=deployment and
<init-param>
    <param-name>configuration</param-name>
    <param-value>deployment</param-value>
</init-param>


on original server.  Can't find them.

Put a breakpoint at WebApplication#getConfigurationType() (https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/da9755e0985ede0e6c9415c82eca378b211fc9f5/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebApplication.java#L823) and see what is going on. Or just overwrite this method to return RuntimeConfigurationType.DEPLOYMENT

I can see it's in debug mode.  If I'm using the same .jar between the servers, and the same jetty folder, it's not something in code.  It seems like there's a setting someplace.

By using the debugger you can see which setting sets the DEBUG mode.

I was able to trace back through and find how it was being set.  Appreciate the help!
